# SQL Developer - trying to import an excel file into a table

Tags: oracle, excel

I'm trying to import an excel file into a table. The excel file has dates in the following format: `20/08/2008  12:00:00 AM`
and I am telling SQLDEV the following: `DD/MM/YYYY H24:MI:SS AM`

To import the file, I am right clicking on the table in SQL Developer, hitting import data and then selecting the file, I map the columns and set the format to above and get the above error. Here's the table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table DRUG_INFO_NOS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" 
   (    "DIN" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TRADE_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "FORM" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "GENERIC_NAME" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
    "MANUFACTURER" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CR_DATE" DATE, 
    "NOC_DATE" DATE, 
    "FIRST_CLAIM_DATE" DATE, 
    "SEQUENTIAL_ID" NUMBER
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATAL03" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table DRUG_INFO_NOS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" MODIFY ("DIN" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" MODIFY ("TRADE_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" MODIFY ("GENERIC_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" MODIFY ("MANUFACTURER" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "DANIEL"."DRUG_INFO_NOS" MODIFY ("SEQUENTIAL_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

but I am getting the above error. What's up?

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  Post the error message, structure and data-types of existing table in db. and what steps you are using to import excel file. How many spaces are in that excel date you provided? Looks like there are 2 spaces between date and time. Not sure if this could be an issue...

Comment: I fixed the 2 spaces problem, but I'm still getting the same error. I will update the question shortly.

Comment: You should use the "insert script" option in order to actually see what SQL Dev is doing, and fix it on the way. I did a test and I saw that date formats from excel files doesn't import hour data in SQL Dev. May be a bug. Your best option is to save the excel file into a CSV, and import it from there.

Comment: What "above error?" There is no error message in your question.

Comment: I probably edited it and accidentally removed that. Would've been a better question to ask 7 months ago :P

Answer (score -1):

This link shows how to deal with importing excel file and invalid date format: [how-to-import-excel-to-oracle](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Would be good to have a little explanation here, instead of just the Link. It will be helpfull.

Comment: I already looked at that page before posting here, it didn't help.